# Gradient fade spacer renders with a different width

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of code which renders the spacer to the entirety of a window, but I only want it to be as wide as the text below it. This rendering is a gradient fade.

What am I doing wrong?
I tried overflow, background-repeat, repeat, moving them both into a table.

```css
.body {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #26BFBF;
}

.toplogo {
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.h1 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #262626;
  margin: 0 40px 0 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#26BFBF, #ffffff);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body class="body" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <div class="toplogo" align="center">
    <a href="xxx" target="_blank">
      <img class="light-img" src="xxx" alt="" style=""> </a>
  </div>

  <div class="spacer">
    <br>>
  </div>

  <div class="h1">
    Newly published material
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I build the spacer and text so that the gradient fade of the spacer is the same width as the text of H1, and changes depending on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

To fit the gradient to the width of the h1, we have to set its width the same as the h1's width.

Also, there was a typo in the HTML code.

Take a look, and tell me whether this was you wanted to achieve, or not:

```css
.body {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #26BFBF;
}

.toplogo {
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.h1 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #262626;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#26BFBF, #ffffff);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 222px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body class="body" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <div class="toplogo" align="center">
    <a href="xxx" target="_blank">
      <img class="light-img" src="xxx" alt="" style=""> </a>
  </div>

  <div class="spacer">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="h1">
    Newly published material
  </div>
</body>
```